# sqlalchemy from_statement dynamic attributes for python objects

Tags: python, dynamic, attributes, sqlalchemy

I have such model:

```
class Test(db.Model, UnicodeMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    subject = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)

    additional = None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'<Test {0}>'.format(self.id)
```

Some code generate RAW SQL for very difficult `SELECT` from db with additional dynamic data.

For example it like:

```
db.session.query(Test).from_statement("SELECT test.id AS test_id, test.subject AS test_subject, 99 AS additional FROM test").all()
```

It generate list of python objects `Test`, but how I can fill attribute `additional` for these python objects?

I don't want store `NULL` column `additional` in database.

I want create dynamic additional data with SQL and add it to python objects.

Help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
db.session.query(Test, "additional").from_statement(
    """
    SELECT test.id AS test_id, test.subject AS test_subject, 99 AS additional
    FROM test
    """
).all()
```

It will return a list of tuples in the (Test object,additional) structure.

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks for sharing! I use it to get total count in one query: `count(1) OVER() AS total_count`